# Ubuntu Nextcloud server stopped working with error on SQUASHFS

Tags: server, ssd, nextcloud

Nextcloud is not running anymore, but I can access the server:

[image: screenshot before login]

I booted with "rescuefix" and started GParted:

[image: gparted with rescuefix]

The Ubuntu install seems to be somehow a RAID or logical volume, because for Nextcloud the SSD was full.

smartctl:
[Result of long test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIHr0.png)

Now I have no idea where to start to get Nextcloud running again. I also missed making backups.

Please let me know which information I need to provide to find the root cause.

df -h shows the following:

```bash
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              777M  1.5M  776M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   57G   53G  1.4G  98% /
tmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              777M  4.0K  777M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I cannot execute any binaries from remote (nano for example):

```
-bash: /usr/bin/nano: Input/output error
```

Nextcloud is installed as a snap. How can I recover my Nextcloud? With fsck? By copying the snap to another Ubuntu server?

Comment: The messages I see are *read-only file system*, which is a problem which should be explored by an administrator of the system. It maybe the result of *unclean* shutdown, failure or other operational issue the owners/admins should be aware of. Depending on the system, simply performing normal file-system checks if errors are found, will be corrected & normal operation will resume after that. IO errors on disk imply disk failure.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  Explore the issue before you fix though (*IO errors should **not** be ignored!*)

Comment: Typically this would be signs of a failing disk.

Comment: I don't see anything RAID-related in the output. The very bottom of your output shows I/O Errors (often hardware fault, but not always) while reading squashfs (usually a snap package). If you installed Nextcloud from a snap, that would explain why Nextcloud is not working -- the system cannot currently read that part of the disk, so cannot load Nextcloud.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; but I'd be exploring the system logs for the first error message you had, as that usually is most critical with subsequent problems a consequence of that first issue... We're limited to being *generic* as we weren't provided with details as to your system (Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu *flavor*?  what release of that product? etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an image of the disk via mSATA-to-USB, bought a new SSD, wrote back the image and it worked. Now I will set up a backup script.

The more often I started the computer with the defect SSD, the more files got lost and in the end the computer even did not start with the defect SSD. So it is true: The earlier you take a snapshot from a defect drive, the better.